# Is It possible to store multiple values store in the option tag after selection? in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.5

My problem is that I display all the attribute drop down and here we get attribute id in the `value="{{$play->id}}"` after select and store to select `name="attribute_id"` and fetch attribute id easily , but we want to store the `attribute id + attribute unit` like `$play->unit` of specific attribute that selected , is it possible to get the multiple values after option selected or any alternative method to solve this problem ?

My code is something like that

```
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_id" id="attribute_id">

     @foreach($plays as $play)

     <option class="form-control" value="{{$play->id}}" >{{$play->attribute}}</option>

     @endforeach

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set value as :

```
<option class="form-control" value="{{$play->id}}**{{$play->unit}}" >{{$play->attribute}}</option>
```

You will get both values after submit.
You need to explode() like:

```
$attribute = $_POST['attribute'];
$values = explode("**", $attribute);
echo $values[0];  //will contain id
echo $values[1];  // will contain unit
```

I am using "**" as a separator, you can use anything.

Comment: Thanks sir your answer is almost nearest to my problem , i am using laravel and here issue is for string conversion on this line check it? $attribute = $_POST['attribute_id'];
$values = explode("**", $attribute);               
$rates->attribute_unit = $request->$values; ...... <<----at this line we give error of Array to string conversion??

Comment: @DanishButt: Updated my post how you can access values

Comment: Thanks Sir i will try it.

Comment: Sir again same error i will try this as well ,                                    
        $attribute = $_POST['attribute_id'];
        $values = explode("**", $attribute);
        $rates->attribute_id = $request->$values[0];
        $rates->attribute_unit = $request->$values[1];

Comment: check if you are getting the values in $_POST?

Comment: Thanks Sir the value come here and we get by dd() that is equal to var_dump and show me value of like that ?  "2**10%"   , Here 2 is the attribute id , and 10 is the attribute uni , but issue when we assign this value to varchar type variable?? How? and thanks sir

Comment: when we assign this value to varchar its give me an error of that , so please give me solution of last point? and thanks sir in advance

Comment: Thanks sir you are superb and give me a 100% accurate solution of my problem , thankewww Soooooo Much Sir...!! Perfect man